# VueJS: how to reference this.$store in component data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am wanting to use my Vuex store data in my app and template.

My Veux store:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var Vuex = require('vuex');

Vue.use(Vuex)

let store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            user: {},
        },
    }
}
module.exports = store
```

I want to use the store data in my app and display it in the template. But, when setting the data in the `data` property, `this.$store` is `undefined`. I am, however, able to access it in the `beforeRender` function:

```
var Vue = require('vue'),
store = require('../../link/to/my/store');

module.exports = {
    el: '#selector',

    store,

    components: {},

    data: {
        saving: false,
        user: this.$store.state.user // this.state is not available here
    },

    created: function(){},
    beforeCreate: function() {

        console.log(this.$state.state) // this.$state is available here

        // i get my data in the form of a json string from the dom
        // and update the global store with the data
        let user = document.querySelector('#user-data')
        if (user) this.$store.dispatch('updateUser', JSON.parse(user.innerHTML))

    },

    methods: {}

    }
};
```

I have also tried with a computed property but to no avail.

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

Comment: Sorry i am afraid that this.$store is still not defined so i am unable to use this.$store.getters.getterMethod()

Comment: data needs to be a function: https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

Comment: Yep thats correct!! in the documentation it only mentions returning data as a function in a component but for anyone else who has this issue, return data as a function for your apps as well!  PS thanksd add this as an answer and i will give you correct answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/):

> When defining a component, data must be declared as a function that returns the initial data object.

So, change:

```
data: {
    saving: false,
    user: this.$store.state.user
},
```

to this:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    saving: false,
    user: this.$store.state.user
  };
}
```

Then the `this` in the function will have a reference to `$store`.